# Normalization of stack of features in Google Earth Engine (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, normalize

How to normalize a stack of features in the google earth engine? Features are the image type you can see the Javascript code here. I'm going to normalize ***features*** between 0,1 values.

Can you provide suggestions and snippets?

```
var ***features*** = (feature 1

    .addBands(feature 2)
    .addBands(feature 3)
    .addBands(feature 4) 
    .addBands(feature 5)
    .addBands(feature 6)
    .addBands(feature 7)
    .addBands(feature 8)
    .addBands(feature 9)
    .addBands(feature 10)
    .addBands(feature 11)
    .addBands(feature 12)
    .addBands(feature 13)
    )
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can you provide a working sample code to show what you want to convert?

Comment: This is exactly what i want to do! Each feature is an image.

Comment: Do you want to normalize across the image stack or for each band individually?

Comment: For each band individiually. All the bands(images) have has the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Normalization is simple all you have to do is find min and max value per band and normalize each band. Below is the code for doing so, add this in a map function to apply it for every band. Function useful here in unitScale.

**Note:** it does not clamp the values greater than 1 which means if you specify the wrong max value the normalized values can be greater or smaller than 1.

```
// Stats will have min max for every band
var stats = image.reduceRegions({
   collection: image.geometry(),
   reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
   scale: //your image scale,
});

print(ee.Feature(stats));

// Normalizing just B1
var norm_image = image.select('B1')
                 .unitScale(stats.get('B1_min'),stats.get('B1_max'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I add to map function to apply it for every band?